# Chrome Console giving ILLEGAL TOKEN error

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, character-encoding

Disclaimer: I am very new to developing (2nd year CS major), so please bear with me.
I am currently developing a chrome extension that pulls JSON data from a page and then displays the data in the extension through an HTML table.

I am using a chrome extension template that is available through Visual Studios.
Since I do not have the reputation, I cannot post the link for reference, but if you were to type "chrome extension Visual Studios" in google, it is the first link.

I am using a jQuery plugin for tables called "DataTables" that is downloaded through Visual Studios.

Whenever I run the solution from Visual Studios on a test "index.htm" file, I get this error in the console:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
>
> > jquery.dataTables.min.js:1
> >
> > popup.js:1

[This is how the console reads "jquery.dataTables.min.js"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zpfZ8.png) Which is a file that is downloaded with the plugin and is referenced in the HTML file according to the plugin's installation instructions. 
 The console reads "popup.js" in the same fashion.

**The Question:** Why is the console reading my two files in this way?

I have looked over every single question on StackOverflow pertaining to this error and have tried every solution that was given, to no avail.

> 1. I have checked multiple times for any sign of a Unicode 200b "Zero-Width Space"
> 2. I have set the default font to Times New Roman, and have the encoding set to UTF-8 for all files.
> 3. The network diagnostic in the console [shows that all these files have loaded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O4NRs.png) and when I run the html file through a text editor, the solution works. I have a fully sort-able table displaying the dummy data.

I assume that most of you are familiar with the layout of a chrome extension (manifest, html file, javascript files, icon.png).
    Here is the respective code for the HTML and JS (I believe the manifest and icon are irrelevant for my question)

**"popup.html" HTML (Jquery/JS/CSS references and a table to hold the data):**

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/DataTables/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="app/popup.js"></script>
<link href="css/classic.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<title>Popup</title>
<body> 
   <table id="example" class="display" width="100"></table>
</body>
</html>
```

**"popup.js" JAVASCRIPT (hardcoded JSON data with a function using "Datatables" library to initialize table headings)**

```
var dataSet = [
       ["00001", "John", "Smith"],
       ["00002", "Jane", "Doe"],
       ["00003", "Ted", "Johnson"],
       ["00004", "Betty", "Smith"],
       ["00005", "Susan", "Wilson"],
       ["00006", "John", "Doe"],
       ["00007", "Bill", "Watson"],
       ["00008", "Walter", "Wright"]
];




  $(document).ready(function () {
 $('#example').DataTable({
    data: dataSet,
    columns: [
        { title: "Emp. Number" },
        { title: "First Name" },
        { title: "Last Name" }
    ]
});
  alert('If i loaded, it loaded');
});
```

Comment: Why are you including two versions of jQuery? That is a bad idea.

Comment: Can you verify the second jquery loaded correctly? May be you forget "http:" in src. By the way, load one of those jQuery files and you can also serve this content from your project folder like you did for DataTables and popup js files.

Answer (score 0):

First, may I suggest trying to load the JS file from a CDN (your display of the resource was rather odd) [this is a common javascript CDN](http://www.jsdelivr.com/) and if you are unable to do so, check to makesure that the datatables file is in fact, javascript.

Secondly, it appears as though you are loading jQuery once at the top and then again with the datatables JS (if, in fact, it is actually loading)

Comment: [Check this link out for downloading DataTables](https://www.datatables.net/download/index)